# file upload forms inside main form

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload

i need to have a form when you press the main submit button all the stuff in it is submitted:
textareas, input and fileupload but i dont understand how can this be done because fileuploads require their own submit button

right now i have this

```
<form method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Title Eng: <input type="text" name="title_Eng" class="submit01" value="<?php echo $_POST["title_Eng"]; ?>"/></td>
<td>Title It: <input type="text" name="title_It" class="submit01" value="<?php echo $_POST["title_It"]; ?>"/></td>
<td>Title Fr: <input type="text" name="title_Fr" class="submit01" value="<?php echo $_POST["title_Fr"]; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 5px;">
<tr><td valign="top">Desc Eng:</td><td><textarea class="textArea01" name="desc_Eng"><?php echo $_POST["desc_Eng"]; ?></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">Desc It:</td><td><textarea class="textArea01" name="desc_It"><?php echo $_POST["desc_It"]; ?></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">Desc Fr:</td><td><textarea class="textArea01" name="desc_Fr"><?php echo $_POST["desc_Fr"]; ?></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit event in Marrakech" class="submit" name="submit_event_in_marrakech"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and i need inside of this form multiple file uploads that get sent once the main submit button is pressed because all this data is inserted in a same row in the db, any thoughts on how can this be achieve?
thanks

Comment: I'm upvoting this question. I think it is a good question. Too often on S.O. contributors don't understand the context the question is coming from. I arrived here because I have two file upload lines in the middle of a long form. The owner doesn't want a submit button for the main form. Whether or not I agree with him, the only answer to the file upload must be that I add separate "inner" forms for the files. My solution is to add iframe forms within the parent page, separate iframes for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website should guide you: [file upload](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html).
Just as a note, there is no need for a separate submit button for a file or files.

Comment: but you still need a enctype="multipart/form-data" code for file upload wich you dont need for normal inputs, so this would make two form submissions ?

Comment: @tada the example in that website also has a text field, so it should be possible to use a single form and get normal data as well as files with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: yes true but i finally made my form submission as a multipart/page submission.
regards